# What are the dangers of unblocking ports to remotely connect to a network?

Tags: ports

I am trying to create something like a cloud where I will be able to connect to a device from other networks, apart from my local one. In order to do that my provider must unblock some ports... My question is what are the actual dangers of this? Can an outsider actually "hack" me and take personal data or something? And is there any easy way to avoid that?

Comment: If there is a vulnerability on the port the server can be compromised sort of like the bash shell vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a port with and set a program to listen that port you open yourself to discovered and undiscovered vulnerability's. When you open a port it is possible for someone to use that port to break into your system however if you keep the program running on that port up to date hackers will have a very little chance of breaking in to your system.

Comment: Can you give me a bit more of details...My provider told me that he will open around 1000 ports, I will only be using 2...what about the other ones can someone connect to them and break in my system? Also when you say up to date what do you mean? The only protection that I have in my system is the one given to me by my provider...

Comment: It would be best if you can get your provider to only open the ports that you need. A port itself is not vulnerable. Only the application(Program) listening on that port can be vulnerable. By the term up to date I mean say you have apache v1.1 running on port 80 and the latest version of apache is v1.2 then keeping up to date would mean installing apache v1.2 Apache is a web server program.